# Explainability of groups mix affect on overall mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am stuck on understanding the best way to approach this problem from a purely statistical/mathematical way.

Say that I have this data in the table below. It shows the comparison of prices for one hotel between two years with a breakdown of the board type and room type.

| Hotel | Board | Room | 2023 Price | 2024 Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HB | A | 1000 | 1100 |
| 1 | HB | B | 1600 | 1850 |
| 1 | FB | A | 1500 | 1750 |
| 1 | FB | B | 1900 |  |
| 1 | FB | C | 2250 | 2250 |
| 1 | ALL | A |  | 2000 |
| 1 | ALL | B | 2600 | 2750 |

Within this data, as a human I can easily tell that most of the prices go up year on year and from the averages below I can also understand this too

2023 average - 1808

2024 average - 1950

However when eyeballing the data I can also see there are some mix differences that will be affecting the overall mean, for example

Board type of "ALL" averages:

2023 average - 2600

2024 average - 2375

Here we can see that because of a lack of data in 2023 for the room type "A" for the board type "ALL" there looks to be a step back in price. This then may actually be artificially increasing the overall mean for this hotel and thus showing a smaller increase in price year on year.

What I want to try and understand - is there a technique out there that will be able to show and explain the drivers affecting the yearly overall means across all groups?